# Check State of Multiple Services in Batch

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have the following script to check the state of a service, which works fine. But I can't figure out how to adjust this to do many services. The outcome would send an email if any of the services were not running with the email specifying what services were not running.

I could just repeat this for each service to check but would be better if there was a way to condense it into one block of code if possible. Any Ideas?

```
Set Service=Service1

for /F "tokens=3 delims=: " %%H in ('sc query %Service%      ^| findstr "        STATE"') do (
if /I "%%H" NEQ "RUNNING" (
echo %Service% is not Running >> ServiceCheck.txt
call "Email Script with the ServiceCheck log attached"
net start %Service%
)
REM Do nothing
)
```

Appreciate the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for /f "delims=" %A in (servicelist.txt) do sc query %A |findstr /c:"STOPPED"&&echo %A>>servicestart.log&sc start %A>>servicestart.log
```

This goes through a list of services in servicelist.txt and writes anything it starts to servicestart.log.

Remember in a batch %A becomes %%A.

```
& seperates commands on a line.

&& executes this command only if previous command's errorlevel is 0.

|| (not used above) executes this command only if previous command's errorlevel is NOT 0

> output to a file

>> append output to a file

< input from a file

| output of one command into the input of another command

^ escapes any of the above, including itself, if needed to be passed to a program
```

Comment: Thanks phd443322. The script works great. I have been playing around with it to try and get it to only write to the file if the service is not Running. This way I can email an alert of down services if the file exists (will only exist if services are down). I have been unable to get this extra bit to work though. Could you show me how to add this?

Comment: It does it here, it does it because findstr finds "STOPPED" so errorlevel is 0. Only if 0 does the command after && execute (which is where it logs). I didn't test it under all circumstances but try brackets around parts if executing wrongly.